# ListBox Index returns negative value

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, listbox, listboxitem, selectedindex

I'm creating a windows phone app using MVVM light pattern. I'm having trouble on my list box as it always returning a negative value (-1) for selected index. Does anyone knows how to resolve it?

here is my code in View Model, do i missed anything?Thanks!

```
 public void OnViewListSelectedItem(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        ListBox lb = new ListBox();

        if (e.AddedItems.Count == 1)
        {
            if (lb.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                _navigationService.NavigateTo(new Uri(ViewModelLocator.ByVendorUrl, UriKind.Relative));
            }

            if (lb.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    _navigationService.NavigateTo(new Uri(ViewModelLocator.ByVendorUrl, UriKind.Relative));
                }
            if (lb.SelectedIndex == 2)
                {
                    _navigationService.NavigateTo(new Uri(ViewModelLocator.ByCombinationUrl, UriKind.Relative));
                }
            }
    }
```

XAML code Here

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lbviewlist">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                            <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ViewListCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <ListBox.Items>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="By Product" FontSize="35" Margin="10,12,12,0"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="By Vendor" FontSize="35" Margin="10,12,12,0"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="By Best Combination" FontSize="35" Margin="10,12,12,0"/>
                    </ListBox.Items>
                </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new ListBox() (called lb) in your code. You don't populate it, so it will be empty and will always have a SelectedIndex of -1

Then check the 'Source' property of 'e' and cast it to a ListBox

```
ListBox myList = (ListBox) e.Source;
```

You can then access the properties on myList.

Comment: thanks, I just realized that its wrong to create new listbox. However, do you know how can I check the selection state of my lblistview?
I don't know how to access/ the lblistview from my code. The only accessible is the (e). Can you help me? Please. Thanks a lot

Comment: You named it in the XAML, so you can just access it from its name (lbviewlist)

In Visual Studio just type the name, and a '.' and you'll see the available properties, events and methods.

Comment: I cannot access it from its name since I'm not coding from code behind, I'm using View Model instead. The only way to access it is thru (e)-parameter of my method ViewListCommand, which is binded to the event of my listbox. But when I literally type (e) in my ViewModel the only available option is AddedItems as shown on my code above.

Comment: Oh I see..e should have a 'Source' property that points to the control:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionchangedeventargs.aspx

Comment: Hello to you, i apologize for so many questions. I'm just a newbie in the technology. Would you mind to teach me how to add a source property to (e). Thank you again, I'm striving to learn.

Comment: No problem...see my answer above :)

ListBox myList = (ListBox) e.Source;

Comment: thanks so much for the patience. So glad you help me.

But its kinda weird that the (e) does not have a 'Source' property, only originalsource, addeditems and removeditems are available. myList is still returning null value. What is wrong with my code :( 

I really apologize if I kept on asking.

I also tried to use the three properties stated above but still returning null value. :(

Comment: Send me your source (lmoroney-at-yahoo-dot-com), and I'll take a look

Comment: I already did it. Thanks for your help. I just did some modifications on your answer, will post mine shortly. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

based on my research SelectedIndex property of listbox is not bindable, when you use the get accessor for the SelectedIndex property, it always returns -1. An attempt to use the set accessor for the SelectedIndex property raises a NotSupportedException. -- [MSDN List selectedporperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist.selectedindex%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I also updated my code since my first code is wrong that creates new listbox and that results to empty/null. Also selectionchanged event does not have a problem to be used as event.

```
    public void method (SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {


        {                
            if (e.AddedItems.Count == 1)
            {
                var listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)e.AddedItems[0];
                string _string1 = "Test";
                if ((string)listBoxItem.Content == _string1)
                {
                    navigationService.NavigateTo(new Uri(ViewModelLocator.page1, UriKind.Relative));
                }
            }
         }
}
```

Thats it. Hope it helps! :)